# Error all module Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I don't know, and then appeared this error, but now I can't run any Scrapy spider.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Eugene/Scrapy/Test/Test_news.py", line 37, in <module>
    crawler.configure()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 46, in configure
    self.extensions = ExtensionManager.from_crawler(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\middleware.py", line 50, in from_crawler
    return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\middleware.py", line 29, in from_settings
    mwcls = load_object(clspath)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\misc.py", line 42, in load_object
    raise ImportError("Error loading object '%s': %s" % (path, e))
ImportError: Error loading object 'scrapy.webservice.WebService': No module named parse
```

Anybody got any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If it was working before, try re-installing it:

```
pip uninstall Scrapy
```

then:

```
pip install -U Scrapy
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is the first thing I did when the error occurred, but it did not help. The error is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have `sudo`, I do this every time to install Scrapy on a brand new ubuntu.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y libffi-dev python-dev python-pip python-lxml
sudo pip install scrapy
```

Also, make sure you are not in a weird situation where you happen to be in a customized folder called scrapy or there are some local files you created conflict with the namespace that scrapy is using.... 
In a short sentence, maybe go to `/tmp`, and try `scrapy startproject myproject` and try to copy the code there without using any controversial name, see if the problem will go away.